# Signaling in opentok textchat

Tags: android, ios, xcode, opentok, tokbox

I am working on opentok text chat.In that for one to one chat what type signaling i have to use.From this [link](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/signaling/ios/)

I have to pass "OTConnect" object to

```
[session signalWithType:type string:@"hello" connection:_connection error:&error];
```

But my session delegate methods are not called.Please give me idea to solve this.

Comment: They have released stuff for text chat: https://github.com/opentok/textchat-acc-pack

Comment: Your openTok delegate method is in same class? Make sure it should be in same class.